# ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python likely shutting down Exception ignored in: <function InheritableThread.__del__ at 0x7f0b958177a0> Pyspark

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
Exception ignored in: <function InheritableThread.**del** at 0x7f0b958177a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 321, in **del**
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

I am getting above error when my GlueJob gets completed, I am using Pyspark InheritableThread.

Also there is zero impact on my process but getting this error which is annoying.

I have tried using thread.join(), and I have tried putting the time.sleep(12) in the end of the program and also I have tried setting thread as daemon but nothing is working.
I want to close the program without throwing the above exception and this exception is getting for every single thread I am running.

Answer (score 0):

in the case you use selenium, it must be in version 3.0, right ?try adding "driver.quit()" at the end

this error "ImportError: sys.meta_path is None" because python session finishes before its object does

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/10235